# Proof of the General Stokes Theorem in Munkres

Tags: analysis, manifolds

In "Analysis on manifolds" Munkres proves the general Stokes theorem
$ \int_{\partial M}\omega = \int_Md\omega $ in the case where the support of $ \omega$ can be covered by a single coordinate patch and says the general case can be easily proved from that. However, I have found myself having quite a bit of trouble with this.
If  $ \{ \phi_i \} $ is a partition of unity on M, we have $ \int_M\eta = \sum_i\int_M\phi_i\eta $ by definition.

So, for $ \omega $, I compute:
$ \int_Md\omega = \sum_i\int_M\phi_id\omega = \sum_i\int_{U_i}\alpha_i^*(\phi_id\omega) = \sum_i\int_{U_i}(\phi_i \circ \alpha_i)d\alpha_i^*\omega$, where $ \alpha_i:U_i \to V_i $ is a coordinate patch on M with the support of $ \phi_i $ contained in $ V_i $.

On the other hand, $ \int_{\partial M}\omega = \sum_i\int_{\partial M}\phi_i\omega = \sum_i\int_Md(\phi_i\omega) = \sum_i\int_{U_i}d(\alpha_i^*(\phi_i\omega)) = \sum_i\int_{U_i}d((\phi_i \circ \alpha_i)(\alpha_i^*\omega)) $, which looks quite similar to the previous expression, but not really equal to it. Can I get some suggestions about what I'm missing here?

Edit: Ok, now I'm aware of the simple proof
 $ \omega = \phi_1\omega + ... + \phi_k\omega$

$ \int_{M}d\omega = \int_Md(\sum_i\phi_i\omega) = \sum_i\int_Md(\phi_i\omega) = \sum_i\int_{\partial M}\phi_i\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega $.

But I'd still like to know where I went wrong in my initial attempt.

Comment: Dang. I just typed up the simple proof, half a minute later you finish your edit :(

Comment: I've added some explanation about your approach. If that's enough for you, maybe we can convince a moderator to cancel the bounty, otherwise, I'll gladly delete my answer to let others try to gain the bounty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was just what I was hoping for!
And what do you mean by "cancel the bounty"? Isn't it supposed to unrefundable? Also, since you gave me an entirely satisfying answer, shouldn't you get that reputation?

Comment: Nice. Let's see if we can get the bounty cancelled.

Comment: It just feels wrong to take the bounty. I had the tab open since yesterday, and just hadn't found the time to answer before you placed your bounty. And you may need it for the next question. But on the other hand, it's just internet points, if the bounty stays, so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt that led to

$$\int_{\partial M}\omega = \sum_i\int_{\partial M}\phi_i\omega = \sum_i\int_Md(\phi_i\omega) = \sum_i\int_{U_i}d(\alpha_i^*(\phi_i\omega)) = \sum_i\int_{U_i}d((\phi_i \circ \alpha_i)(\alpha_i^*\omega))$$

isn't wrong, you just didn't take it far enough.

You have $\alpha_i^\ast\left(d\phi_i\omega\right)$ - it's in my opinion nicer to have the pull-back outside here. Then you differentiate to get

$$\alpha_i^\ast\left(d\phi_i\wedge\omega + \phi_id\omega \right) = \alpha_i^\ast(d\phi_i\wedge\omega) + \alpha_i^\ast \phi_id\omega.$$

Now the second part is exactly what you want, and all that remains is that the first,

$$\alpha_i^\ast (d\phi_i \wedge\omega),$$

sums to $0$ because we have $\sum\limits_i \phi_i \equiv 1$.

---

The proof usually goes

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\partial M} \omega &= \int_{\partial M} \sum_i \phi_i\omega\\
&= \sum_i \int_{\partial M} \phi_i\omega\\
&= \sum_i \int_M d(\phi_i\omega)\\
&= \sum_i \int_M (d\phi_i \wedge \omega + \phi_id\omega)\\
&= \sum_i \int_M d\phi_i \wedge \omega + \sum_i \int_M \phi_id\omega\\
&= \int_M \left(\sum_i d\phi_i\right)\wedge \omega + \int_M \left(\sum_i\phi_i\right)d\omega\\
&= \int_M d\left(\sum_i \phi_i\right)\wedge\omega + \int_M d\omega\\
&= \int_M 0\wedge\omega + \int_M d\omega\\
&= \int_M d\omega.
\end{align}$$